# Divs to change multiple color when click

Tags: javascript, html, click

I'm trying to get other divs to light up when one is clicked. For instance, when you click on the first div, I want that to change color as well as the 3rd.

What I have so far is this: http://jsfiddle.net/r5WWQ/147/

```
<div class="place"></div>
<div class="place2"></div>
<div class="place3"></div>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Just add `$(".place3").toggleClass("yellow");` to the first (or whatever) function. Or is there anything more tricky required?

Comment: Thanks for the input. Nothing more tricky than that.

Answer (score 1):

Simply toggle all the colors when you click on one of the `div`'s:

```
$("div").click(function () {
   $(".place").toggleClass("green");
   $(".place2").toggleClass("orange yellow");
   $(".place3").toggleClass("yellow");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r5WWQ/148/

You can manipulate this so that only the third and first would light up when clicking one of them:

```
$(".place, .place3").click(function () {
   $(".place").toggleClass("green");
   $(".place3").toggleClass("yellow");
});
```